# Python seaborn graphics

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, kaggle

Dear all I'm trying to apply a kaggle tutorial code to the Iris dataset.

Unfortunately when I excecute the code for the graph I can only see this output without seeing any graph:

`matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x9abf9b0`

any idea?

this is the code

```
import warnings # current version of seaborn generates a bunch of warnings that we'll ignore
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)

# Next, we'll load the Iris flower dataset, which is in the "../input/" directory
iris = pd.read_csv("../input/Iris.csv") # the iris dataset is now a Pandas DataFrame

# We'll use this to make a scatterplot of the Iris features.
iris.plot(kind="scatter", x="SepalLengthCm", y="SepalWidthCm")
```

Comment: might need `%%matplotlib inline` or `iris.plot(...).show()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IPython Notebook, simply use the `%pylab inline` command before you make your plot. If not, try `plt.show()` after you make your plot.